# PHP - Group Array by Key Value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, group-by

Trying to group an array depending on whether it's index is divisible by there.  I've tried various combinations of for loops and foreach loops and if($i % 3 == 0) ... But, it's not outputting the way I need it.

Here is a greatly simplified array (the original data contains a lot of highly sensitive information...)

The original array looks similar to this:

```
$item[0]['Section 1']['Item 2'] => 1334;
$item[1]['Section 2']['Item 3'] => 15454;
$item[2]['Section 3']['Item 4'] => 1452;
$item[3]['Section 4']['Item 5'] => 1341;
$item[4]['Section 5']['Item 6'] => 1788655;
$item[5]['Section 6']['Item 7'] => 13;
$item[6]['Section 7']['Item 8'] => 142;
$item[7]['Section 8']['Item 9'] => 15678;
$item[8]['Section 9']['Item 10'] => 15542;
$item[9]['Section 10']['Item 11'] => 16578;
$item[10]['Section 11']['Item 12'] => 18452;
$item[11]['Section 12']['Item 13'] => 16565;
```

I'm trying to group every 3 records, like this:

```
$newitem[0]['Section 1']['Item 2'] => 1334;
$newitem[0]['Section 2']['Item 3'] => 15454;
$newitem[0]['Section 3']['Item 4'] => 1452;
$newitem[1]['Section 4']['Item 5'] => 1341;
$newitem[1]['Section 5']['Item 6'] => 1788655;
$newitem[1]['Section 6']['Item 7'] => 13;
$newitem[2]['Section 7']['Item 8'] => 142;
$newitem[2]['Section 8']['Item 9'] => 15678;
$newitem[2]['Section 9']['Item 10'] => 15542;
$newitem[3]['Section 10']['Item 11'] => 16578;
$newitem[3]['Section 11']['Item 12'] => 18452;
$newitem[3]['Section 12']['Item 13'] => 16565;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$newindex = 0;
$newitem = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($item); ++$i)
{
    $newindex = (int) $i / 3;
    if(!isset($newitem[ $newindex ]))
        $newitem[ $newindex ] = array();

    $newitem[ $newindex ] = array_merge($newitem[ $newindex ], $item[ $i ]);
}
```

[Link to output](http://pastie.org/private/ccbqpv35o7xk7ns9bzblxw) (dump of `$newitem`)

The trick is `(int) $i / 3`, which takes `$i`, divides it by `3`, then casts to `int` which truncates any decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion use `array_chunk` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
$item = array_chunk($item, 3);
```

Or

```
$newItem = array ();
$x = 0;
$t = 0;
foreach ( $item as $value ) {
    if ($x < 3) {
        $newItem [$t] [$x] = $value;
        $x ++;
    } else {
        $t ++;
        $x = 0;
        $newItem [$t] = array ();
    }
}

var_dump ( $newItem );
```

Comment: The format isn't "wrong", the value of e.g. `$newitem[0]` would just need to be an associative array. So `array_chunk` gets close, but doesn't format it the way he implied he would like it (i.e. it gives a two-dimensional array, `$newitem[0][0]`, `$newitem[0][1]`, `$newitem[0][2]`, `$newitem[1][0]`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

[array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) is the one you need it. and you should iterate the new array as for two dimentional array as you can see that your new array has same index 0 for 3 elements.

try:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php